Сервер возвращает 403 при попытке открыть видео по прямой ссылке
Пишу софтину для скачивания видео с сайта. Раскопал прямую ссылку (https://video.sibnet.ru/v/24b1b8b0733c192f76dc6e32bafbd109/4108163.mp4) на скачивание видео через HTML-разметку на сайте (https://animejoy.ru/tv-serialy/2341-zakazyvali-krolika-3-sezon.html). При переходе по ссылке сервер возвращает 403 Forbidden. Почему я могу смотреть видео через плеер на сайте, но не могу обратиться к нему напрямую?

cookies не сохраняете и не передаете? useragent разный? причин - миллион. разбирайтесь, удачи!

@aleksandrbarakin Cookie не отключал, так что, вероятно, сохраняются.

Referer, Accept, айпишник, нетипичное повдение, не тот регистр заголовков, не те режимы шифрования в TLS... да что угодно может быть, что взбредёт в головы авторов сервиса
